# Raspbian /sys/bus/w1/devices/ is empty when having multiple 1-wire DS18B20 temperature sensors

Tags: raspbian, hardware, 1-wire

I have a RasPi model B rev. 2.0 and two DS18B20 1-wire temperature sensors and they are working individually fine. I know I should be able to [connect multiple 1-wire sensors in parallel](http://www.reuk.co.uk/Connect-Multiple-Temperature-Sensors-with-Raspberry-Pi.htm) but I can't detect any sensors when connecting more than one at the same time (to the same GPIO pin). Individually I can detect each sensor.

This is one of the sensors and the only one connected:
[image: Sensor 1 works OK]

This is the other and the only one connected:
[image: Sensor 2 works OK]

When I connect both in parallel it shows nothing under `/sys/bus/w1/devices/`:
[image: Does not work]

I have connected my sensors to pin 7 (GPIO 7) which is the [dedicated 1-wire pin](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/ds18b20-one-wire-digital-temperature-sensor-and-the-raspberry-pi).

As they work individually, I am pretty sure I am connecting it correctly:

- Red to `3.3V`
- Yellow to `GND`
- Black to `GPIO 7`

And when having multiple sensors I am just connecting both reds, both yellows and both blacks in to a terminal strip.

Is this my sensors being faulty or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE #1, 2014-Dec-18, 22:42**

I am using the built-in pull-up resistor in my Python programming and it has been suggested by @joan that I should try with a real 4.7K Ohm resistor instead as the built-in may be too weak to support multiple sensors.

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/overview there is a section near the end on using multiple sensors and accessing them with the specific serial number. It will also answer your wiring question.

Comment: Where have you connected the pull-up resistor?

Comment: @joan - in my software as I am using the built-in pull-up resistor

Comment: @SteveRobillard - what do you mean I have done wrong? I can't see it

Comment: @DHS The internal pull-up is probably too weak (it's approximately 50 K) for more than one sensor.  It should be about 4K7 (lower resistances allow more current and are called stronger when used as pull-ups/downs).

Comment: @joan - OK... that would make sense. I only have a 10K Ohm resistor available so I can't test this now but I will get the correct resistor eventually and test it. Thanks

Comment: @DHS It's worth trying with the 10K, but the lower value would be more reliable.

Comment: @joan - sadly it doesn't work with the 10K Ohm resistor (between `3.3V` and `GPIO 7`). I will buy a 4K7 Ohm resistor the next time I get to a electronic store and until then I will only have one sensor connected

Comment: Can you connect the resistor using the 5V line instead of the 3.3V line please?

Comment: Also, can you provide a diagram of your layout? And/or pictures. just so we can identify any wiring issues.

Answer (score 2):

On the DS18B20's that I've used, the yellow wire goes to the GPIO pin and black connects to the ground pin. Also, as Joan suggests, use a 4k7 resistor between 3V3 and the GPIO pin. (Only one resistor, regardless of the number of DS18B20's.)

See https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing for more info.

Comment: I think this *could* be an answer, so I rather than converting to a comment, I edited "This should be a comment" out.   I notice the OP has not been back, which may mean the problem was solved w/ the resistor.

Comment: Currently I have given up on this but I will revisit this one day and check if this is the solution